# What is the best way to get substring info from a string

Tags: algorithm, go

I am actually doing a function to get some data. The data has info that it's not necessary for me, so I'am searching for an optimal way to find it.
What I have is this

```
e := strings.Index(result, "Country") //Searching for the country info like Country: US
```

When I get the index I search for the Info that I need something like the next word. That's what I'm looking for.
Any idea to resolve this in an optimal way?

Comment: Welcome to SO! So you are looking for the next element to the one you search or you are looking for a second search? Any programming language?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FindStringIndex](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#example_Regexp_FindStringIndex) from the `regexp` package. It is guaranteed to run in time linear in the size of the input. `FindStringIndex` returns a `slice` of two elements defining the location of the matched string so you can easily get the next word.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your result string looks like but if you can turn it into a format such as "City:San Fran;State:CA;Country:US" then this can easily be converted into a map. For instance:

```
result := "City:San Fran,State:CA,Country:US"
fields := strings.Split(result, ",")
fieldsMap := map[string]string{}
for _, field := range fields {
    pair := strings.Split(field, ":")
    fieldsMap[pair[0]] = pair[1]
}
```

Now you can access any value very easily:
`country := fieldsMap["Country"]` will give "US" if you `fmt.Println(country)`

Answer (score 0):

It is another way to find the index of the string.

Split by that string and then `length of the first index` is the index of the first occurrence of the string.
https://play.golang.org/p/x7QWyuC_1wK

```
    result := "City:San Fran,State:CA,Country:US"

    // split the string 
    s := strings.Split(result, "US")

    // index of US 
    index := len(s[0])

    fmt.Println(index)

// Output
    U 31
```